# PHP Opening file not on webserver for editing

Tags: php, file, fopen, editing

I'm creating a simple script for editing html and php code.
I am using fopen() and fwrite() to open and save files. However, I am only able to open files that are on my web server and not from my computer.
What can I do to make opening files from my computer possible?

I would like to avoid setting up ftp servers and the like because
1) that ultimately defeats the object - might as well set up a local web server
2) I would like for others to be able to download and use the script with little effort

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you ever come across https://c9.io/ ? Really suggest you check that out.

Comment: php is a server-side language, it will only be able to open files that are on the server. You have to upload the file to the server in order to open it with php - you can send it via an html form, as suggested on the answers.

Comment: I use KATE, which opens files remotely, making a temp local copy, and saves my changes remotely. That is only one such program that does that. You appear to be reinventing a utility already invented many times.

Comment: I thought he was asking if it was possible to access a webpage with his script, and edit a file from his computer from there.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. i would need to upload the file from the computer to the server for editing. how would i go about saving the file back to the computer seamlessly?

Comment: @Alex Ahh I get it.  I took "script" to mean "PHP script".  Given the "PHP" in the heading, and the PHP tag.  But given "would like for others to be able to download and use the script...". I'm out.

Comment: An example of what i am trying to do is here: http://edit.orgapage.de - youll see that this site has the ability to edit files via ftp or files stored local to the script user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - based on your comments above and here I think I understand now... ;-)

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input

This will allow someone to upload a file to your PHP-enabled site via their browser (after they browse to your site).

Then, after the file has been saved to the server, your PHP code can use eg `get_file_contents()` to pick up the file and work with it.

The PHP would need to present the file (ie in more HTML) as a download link/button etc, for the user to collect back again after it's been processed.

Comment: that's what i'm using.However, i get the following error: file_get_contents(attack.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `file_get_contents("attack.php")`

Comment: @LeeGinger-NinjaMcCarthy OK so either the file isn't being uploaded to the server, or the `file_get_contents` is failing for some reason.  Have you confirmed the file is actually there?  Check its permissions, and that your PHP context has the correct permissions to read the file.

Comment: @what does not work? Have you confirmed the file is actually on the server, eg by looking with your FTP application or via cPanel etc?

Comment: i think the point has been missed. im now aware that the file cant be directly edited, it must be uploaded first.thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @LeeGinger-NinjaMcCarthy , sorry I didn't _get_ what you were trying to do. I do really appreciate the accept, but if I didn't really answer your question, you don't need to accept my answer (An up vote if you found it useful is sufficient). Leaving the post as "unanswered" by not accepting means someone in future is more likely to come and properly solve it. So you want the site to effectively "open" the file for editing by user? It was your use of the term "script" that threw me (implied some back-end processing).